# Set-DefaultScaffolder : Cannot get an instance of EnvDTE.DTE when debugging T4Scaffolding.Core Nuget package - Advanced Powershell debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, nuget-package, powershell-ise, t4scaffolding

I am trying to debug T4Scaffolding.Core Nuget package from outside Visual Studio 2012.
I am using Powershell ISE with Powershell 3.0 installed and run under CLRVersion 4.0.30319.

I first import several Nuget related items:
- Profile.ps1
- nuget.psm1
- NuGet.Cmdlets.dll

I am also setting the current location to set-location "\ClassLibrary1\"
and obtained the only DTE instance currently running (I previously opened MySolution in VS 2012 that has a class library and an asp.net MVC 4 application in it)

```
$dte = [runtime.interopservices.marshal]::GetActiveObject("visualstudio.dte")
```

I skipped importing Get-Project cmdlet from NuGet.Cmdlets.dll binary module, so I can create my own cmdlets: Get-Project
that gets my MVC project this way:

```
$project = $dte.Solution.Projects.Item("MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1.csproj")
```

I am able to step into init.ps1: 
  \packages\T4Scaffolding.Core.1.0.0\tools\init.ps1
but the code fails when executing:

```
Set-DefaultScaffolder -Name CustomTemplate -Scaffolder T4Scaffolding.CustomTemplate -SolutionWide -DoNotOverwriteExistingSetting


Set-DefaultScaffolder : Cannot get an instance of EnvDTE.DTE
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-DefaultScaffolder -Name CustomTemplate -Scaffolder T4Scaffolding.CustomTempl ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-DefaultScaffolder], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.SetDefaultScaffolderCmdlet
```

I also tried pointing to my $project name (omitting -SolutionWide) with the same results.:

```
Set-DefaultScaffolder -Name CustomTemplate -Scaffolder T4Scaffolding.CustomTemplate -Project ($project).Name -DoNotOverwriteExistingSetting
```

I could observe that EnvDTE.dll is loaded into Powershell ISE environment by using:

```
[System.Threading.Thread]::GetDomain().GetAssemblies()
```

Hopefully someone will be interested in achieving the same goal (stepping line by line through init.ps1 and install.ps1 of a Nuget package outside Visual Studio).

Thanks,
Rad

[Stack Overflow: question I used as a starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031944/how-to-debug-install-ps1-script-of-nuget-package?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I got same error message:

```
Set-DefaultScaffolder : Cannot get an instance of EnvDTE.DTE
```

but in different scenario. I was using scaffold in VS2015, installed T4Scaffolding.Core. Then I found the solution from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727299/is-mvcscaffolding-compatible-with-vs-2013-rc-by-command-line#answer-23673004)

By installing [Windows Management Framework 4.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855) the error is gone and my scaffold works again.
Hopes this can help.