# Is MvcScaffolding compatible with VS 2013 RC by command line?

Tags: nuget-package, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2013

At NuGet when I try to install MvcScaffolding, by typing:

```
Install-Package MvcScaffolding
```

I am getting this error

```
Set-DefaultScaffolder : Cannot get an instance of EnvDTE.DTE
```

Is it happening because of this new scaffolding engine in Visual Studio 2013 ?

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem with visual studio 2013 Ultimate RC

Comment: As of todays date...I am also having this problem.  And none of the prescribed solutions are working

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I emailed [Scott Hanselman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6380/scott-hanselman) about this a few weeks back. Here's his response:

> We've found out what's up and we are going to release a fixed version, although we're taking Scaffolding in a new direction with VS2013 we still want this to work. Thanks for finding this bug.

So I'd keep eyes peeled for a new release of MvcScaffold that will hopefully resolve this. In the mean time, there are [new features for VS2013](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-scaffolding-overview) that take scaffolding in a much-improved direction, so you may want to investigate those.

Edit: There's a new package available (make sure to run VS2013 as admin to get it to work):

`Install-Package MvcScaffolding -Version 1.0.8-vs2013 -Pre`

Comment: The same problem here the error is still not solved, it would be nice if they solve it because I have to start a new project using Visual Studio 2013, it would be very disappointing to have such problem just at its start :D

Comment: I have also this problem and I can't install the package 1.0.8-vs2013, it doesn't install

Comment: For those having problems make sure to run VS2013 as admin

Answer (score 3):

I came across this same bug in VS2015. I pulled the source, fixed the bugs, and uploaded new NuGet packages with linked dependencies. The 3 new packages are:

- [MvcScaffolding.VS2015](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcScaffolding.VS2015/)
- [T4Scaffolding.VS2015](https://www.nuget.org/packages/T4Scaffolding.VS2015/)
- [T4Scaffolding.Core.VS2015](https://www.nuget.org/packages/T4Scaffolding.Core.VS2015/)

If you simply install the [MvcScaffolding](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcScaffolding.VS2015/) package, the other packages will be pulled through. Hope this helps someone else. 
Cheers.

Comment: Worked for me on VS2013 as well.

Answer (score 2):

I found that I had to go into my `.\packages` folder (for the solution) and manually delete all `MvcScaffolding` and `T4Scaffolding` package folders (I have the `NuGet` "`restore packages`" feature enabled that, I thought, would take care to restore anything that I should not have deleted, plus I made a backup).

After that, antinescience's `Install-Package` command for `vs2013` worked fine, and so did the "`Scaffold Controller ...`" to scaffold an MVC5 controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick update, back on time when I wrote this question Visual Studio 2013 was still in   Release Candidate. Now, 8 months later, Microsoft has just released Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 and since then everything is working well with MVCScaffolding.

I've test it in Windows 8 and 7. In Windows 7 it was necessary to install 
[Windows Management Framework 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40855) before.