# How to add WEB API controller via Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013, controller

I tried to add a WEB API controller via EF like this:

[image]

And then I got this error in my Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

[image]

Does anyone know why?

**UPDATE:**

This is the mid picture:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522037/self-referential-loop-issue-mvc-web-api

Comment: Just for testing purposes...can you disable your antivirus and try again?

Comment: I just did that and nothing. @Hackerman

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910162/scaffolding-controller-doesnt-work-with-visual-studio-2013-update-2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522037/self-referential-loop-issue-mvc-web-api

Comment: I have VS Update 5 and the latest Entity Framework installed... Not helping. @Hackerman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall NuGet package as following:

```
Uninstall-Package EntityFramework

Install-Package EntityFramework
```