# MVC scaffolding "Error running selected code generator" (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll denied)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

When trying to create a new controller with views using entity framework, I get the following message:

> Access to the path 
>   'C:\Users\XXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\SOMEGUID\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll' is denied'.

I already saw the [following so thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920837/there-was-an-error-running-the-selected-code-generator-in-vs-2013-scaffolding), but I didn't came up with any solution.

Comment: Try update the nuget package for the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Post this as a solution, I updated it then I got the same message but for Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll. So I updated it too and it worked, many thanks.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update the `NuGet` package for the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core`
You can do this for example from the `Package Manger Console` by typing

```
update-package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core
```