# Error in creating controller classes in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is regarding an error while creating a controller in ASP.NET MVC project.

I have created 3 projects - Model, Data Layer and Web. The Model project contains classes to hold data, Data Layer project contains Context classes and configuration classes. I am using Visual Studio 2015 to develop application. The solution is compiled without any problems. But while creating a new controller using the model in Data project and Context & Configuration classes in Datalayer projects, it throws the following error.

[image]

Comment: Have a Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/25344594/834030

Comment: Thanks. it is a great link. Still figuring out my problem. Will keep the root cause posted as soon I resolve this