# AspNetZero - New controller keeps retuning 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

Somewhat [related to this other posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697823/aspnetzero-net-core-2-0-mvc-version-error-on-adding-new-controller) I have. Due to that issue, I am basically doing a copy/paste of one of my existing (working
) controllers to create a new controller.
So far I have created three new controllers, country, state and address, using the copy/paste method. Two of them are working just fine without any issues.

The third controller address, just keeps returning 404 error pages whenever one of my other pages/controllers tries to launch any method in the "Address" controller. My index method in this controller currently just displays a very simple index page with just a heading and one line of text content. Even this wont open up.

I then created a copy of the address controller named it "test". Then added just an index method, with a very basic index view with no content, just a heading and one line of text.
I added this test controller to the left navigation menu as a new entry and tried to open the index page from there, still it does not work. I keep getting 404 errors!

Here is a snippet from the AspNetZero log file, showing the 404 error.

> INFO  2018-08-06 14:28:17,619 [37   ] ore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker - Executed action EXLNT.NursingOps17.NursingOps.StateAppService.GetStates (EXLNT.NursingOps17.Application) in 42.5497ms
>   INFO  2018-08-06 14:28:17,619 [37   ] soft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost - Request finished in 51.7445ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
>   INFO  2018-08-06 14:29:01,372 [3    ] soft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost - Request starting HTTP/1.1 **GET http://localhost:62114/Nursing/Address**
>   INFO  2018-08-06 14:29:01,376 [3    ] tion.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler - AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.
>   INFO  2018-08-06 14:29:01,376 [3    ] soft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost - **Request finished in 3.6013ms 404**

Here is my controller code:

```
using Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using EXLNT.NursingOps17.Authorization;
using EXLNT.NursingOps17.Web.Controllers;
using Abp.Auditing;
using EXLNT.NursingOps17.NursingOps.AppServices;
using EXLNT.NursingOps17.NursingOps;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Abp.Application.Services.Dto;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using EXLNT.NursingOps17.Web.Areas.Nursing.Models.Address;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using EXLNT.NursingOps17.Core.NursingOps;

namespace EXLNT.NursingOps17.Web.Areas.Nursing.Controllers
{

public class AddressController : NursingOps17ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IListValuesAppService _listValuesAppService;
    private readonly IAddressAppService _addressAppService;
    private readonly ICountryAppService _countryAppService;
    private readonly IStateAppService _statesAppService;

    public AddressController(IAddressAppService addressAppService,
        IListValuesAppService listValuesAppService,
        ICountryAppService countryAppService,
        IStateAppService StatesAppService)
    {
        _addressAppService = addressAppService;
        _listValuesAppService = listValuesAppService;
        _countryAppService = countryAppService;
        _statesAppService = StatesAppService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public PartialViewResult CreateModal()
    {
        //Code removed for brevity
        return PartialView("_CreateModal", viewModel);
    }


    //Edit
    public async Task<PartialViewResult> EditModal(int id)
    {
        //Code removed for brevity
        return PartialView("_EditModal", viewModel);
    }

}
```

}

I have compared everything in this controller to all my other working controllers and I cannot see what I am missing that could be causing this issue?

Comment: The controller is inside an area, so it should be decorated with [Area("Nursing")] unless its done by NursingOps17ControllerBase

Comment: @kajetan kazimierczak you are a genius! The area attribute was missing! Smh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller was not decorated with "Area" attribute. Always the most simple things that trip me up!