# MVC scaffolding not working on converted MVC 3 to 5.2 file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller, scaffolding

[image]
[image]

Hi Folks, I recently upgraded an existing solution from MVC/.NET 3/4 to 5.2/4.5. 
 I'm getting the above error when I right click > add > view.  The frustrating part is that scaffolding works on a brand new project, which I am using to generate code for the older project/solution. I am using VS 2015.

Unfortunately I can't copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates" and paste it to the "12.0" folder - if I were to do this would I just copy the same file directory path?

Is there a way to change the VS configuration for this solution to use the same code generation templates as a newly-created solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does your computer have active internet connection? in my case i connected to the internet and than this problem fad away

Comment: Yes it has active internet

Comment: then go through it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920837/there-was-an-error-running-the-selected-code-generator-in-vs-2013-scaffolding/21272717

Comment: alrighty, I went through all of the items that was marked solution on that to no avail... :(  I'm thinking this has something to do with some config/preference in VS that tells solution where to look for XML for scaffolding, I can't find anything in web config or view/web config or packages that would lead me to it.  Any other clues?

Comment: Any other takers here?  I'm thinking of just rebuilding all solutions, might just be that time to do that