# Can't add controller in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to add a controller in visual studio 2019 and it throws the following error :
[image]

can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: That's strange. Are you perhaps using some kind of exotic name for the controller?

Comment: Or an exotic plugin? (It's complaining about a code generator)

Comment: @StevenLemmens no. whatever name i give, it throws the same error.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ no man. i haven't used any plugin.

Comment: Are you trying to scaffold when making the new controller?

Comment: @Fabulous no, I'm choosing empty mvc controller.

Comment: OP - if you can head over to event viewer and get the stacktrace that might help? Also, I hate to say this, turn it off and on again (VS), it can get itself in a state sometimes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920837/there-was-an-error-running-the-selected-code-generator-in-vs-2013-scaffolding multitude of different suggestions there. All seem to elude to the idea that it's not actually the new controller, it's a problem elsewhere with either platform mismatches or config/proj XML.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ nah, that didn't help either. anyways i created a fresh new project. couldn't solve that.

Comment: @Shiwa the only time I've had issues with the new controller dialogue it mentions scaffolding issues when I'm doing demos. As a result, I always create controllers by adding a new class to the folder which is essentially giving you an empty controller