# MVC 4 with EF6 on Visual Studio 2013 Scaffolding Error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, t4scaffolding

I have just started using Visual Studio 2013 with EF6 and I have created a demo application with MVC 4. I tried to scaffold a controller but i keep getting an error. I have installed MVCScaffolding from the Package Manager Console and everything installed correctly including T4Scaffolding, T4Scaffolding.Core... however I keep getting this error. Please help me out

```
Invoke-Scaffolder : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Student'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Scaffold Controller Student -Repository
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Scaffolder], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :     PositionalParameterNotFound,T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.InvokeScaffolderCmdlet
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks A lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions. I solved this by using this command instead. Worked like a charm.

Install-Package MvcScaffolding -Version 1.0.8-vs2013 -Pre

I got it from [this another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727299/is-mvcscaffolding-compatible-with-vs-2013-rc-by-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Try with MVC 5.