# What are the parameters passed to the 'install.ps1' script of a NuGet package?

Tags: powershell, nuget

I need to know what are those parameters: `$installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project`

Example for `EntityFramework` NuGet package:

***install.ps1***

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

Initialize-EFConfiguration $project
Add-EFProvider $project 'System.Data.SqlClient' 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer'

Write-Host
Write-Host "Type 'get-help EntityFramework' to see all available Entity Framework commands."
```

For what reason are they used for ?

Is there some way to debugging this script ?

Comment: If it's been documented correctly you should be able to use `Get-Help EntityFramework -Full` to show you everything you need to know.

Comment: Just add `Write-Host "$installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project"` to the install.ps1 script, install it and check the output - then you see all the actual parameters...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is a little bit unclear. Are you asking about what the parameters are used for?

- `$installPath` is the path to the folder where the package is
  installed. By default: `$(solutionDir)\packages`
- `$toolPath` is the path to the \tools directory in the folder where the package is installed. By default: `$(solutionDir)\packages\[packageId]-[version]\tools`
- `$package` is a reference to the package object
- `$project` is a reference to the target EnvDTE project object. This object is defined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51h9a6ew(v=VS.80).aspx).

If your question is about debugging `install.ps1` and get actual values for your parameters, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031944/how-to-debug-install-ps1-script-of-nuget-package).

Comment: I also found you can do: $project = 'Get-Project' and then print it by typing: '$project' in the NuGet package console in Visual Studio.

Comment: The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33811810/237091) gives a lot more information about the $project and $packages arguments.